# Section is floating top over the header on mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm not a big Bootstrap fan because I'm facing a lot of unexpected behaviors working with it. Currently, I'm working on a project in which Bootstrap is needed and the problem is the thing is floating over each other.

The First Question: Is clearing overflow is required with grid system ? (clear: I mean we use a grid with specific rules to make things fit inside our page with a specific width and height so what may cause the floating when elements are taking the view width ?)

Second Question: Is there a tool to guide me throw working with Bootstrap to easily figure where's the problem actually?

[image]

```
<div id="bookingForm">
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-3 btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-light font-weight-bold"><i class="fa fa-plane pr-3"></i>Tours</button>
    <button class="btn active font-weight-bold"><i class="fa fa-car pr-2"></i>Rent A Car</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center booking-fields">
<div class="col-md-2 pt-2 text-wrap find-box text-muted d-md-block d-none pr-0">Find Your <b>Destination</b></div>
<div class="col-md-9 row justify-content-center px-0">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 pt-2">
        <label class="text-muted">Where To</label>
        <input type="text" list="destinationList" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose Your Destination">
        <datalist id="destinationList">
            <option value="Sharm El- Shiekh"></option>
            <option value="Hurghada"></option>
            <option value="Aswan"></option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 pt-2">
        <label class="text-muted">From</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datePicker1" placeholder="Enter Date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 pt-2">
        <label class="text-muted">To</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datePicker2" placeholder="Enter Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 booking-btn d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
    <button class="btn btn-block mt-md-2"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
   <section class="features">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <div class="col-md-6 text-uppercase text-center font-weight-bold mt-5">Features</div>               
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>
```

Update: While trying to figure the problem I found that the booking form isn't taking its place on a mobile view which causes the element after to wrap under.

Update 2: I'm setting a fixed height for the header with 100vh to set background for it.